# How can I create a new object every time my program loops?

Tags: java

How my program is set up is that my code runs and allows the user to create a new movie object which is then stored to the constructor. It then gives the option to create a new movie which is then stored in the same movie object, which ultimately overwrites the previous movie object that was created. Many implementation go about putting the object creation in a loop, but this asks for all the multiple values to be stored into multiple objects all at once, I'm not looking to do that. I'm not sure how to go about solving this.
Here's my code
Movie class

```
public class Movie {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] genre;
    private String[] actors;
    private String[] language;
    private String countryOfOrigin;
    private Map<String, Integer> ratings;

    Movie() {
    }

    //Constructor
    public Movie(int id, String name, String description, String[] genre, String[] actors, String[] language, String countryOfOrigin, Map<String, Integer> ratings) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.actors = actors;
        this.language = language;
        this.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    //setters
    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

//getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nMovie Id: " + id + " \nMovie Name: " + name + "\nMovie Description: " + description + "\nMovie Genre(s): " + Arrays.toString(genre) + "\nMovie Actor(s): " + Arrays.toString(actors) + "\nMovie Language(s): " + Arrays.toString(language) + "\nCountry of Origin: " + countryOfOrigin + "\nRatings: " + ratings +"";
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    // --- Private global scanner initialization --- //
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (loopAgain) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int id = rand.nextInt(MAX);

            System.out.println("\nCreate Poll");

            System.out.println("\nEnter the Movie Name: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            Movie movie1 = new Movie(id, name, description, genre, actors, language, countryOfOrigin, mapRatings);

            System.out.println("Create new movie? (y/n): ");
            String answer = input.nextLine();

            if (answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y")) {
                loopAgain = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could put each new movie into an ArrayList, so at the end you have a list of different movies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the movie objects in some kind of container after you create them. So you can use an ArrayList for example

`ArrayList<Movie> movies= new ArrayList<Movie>();`.

You can put this above your while loop. Then after you create the object you can add it into the container such as `movies.add(movie1)` you can put this right under where you called the constructor. Later on to access the object, you can use `movies.get(index)`